# Jhipster architecture application

Tags: angular, spring-boot, architecture, jhipster, diagram

I created app with jhipster generator. I chose monolith system and Angular 8. Now i wonder how can I demonstrate a system using diagrams. I want to present the construction of this system, also when it comes to connecting the application on the client side with the application on the server side.
Could it be something like that?

[image]

And connecting the client-side application to the server-side application looks like this?

[image]

Please give me advice how to present this issue well with diagrams.

I have an additional question whether the application generated with jhipster uses a design pattern like MVC?

Comment: That's actually no UML you're using. Looks more like a mix of DFD and Powerpoint. When it comes to "connecting" that's a behavioral thing and needs to be tackeled with sequence diagrams. The static overview could be done with component diagrams.

Comment: Yes I know that it is no UML but I want to present the architecture system in some way but I don't quite know what it should look like with the application generated using Jhipster. As for the component diagram, what should the diagram look like for this type of application?

Comment: Are you sure you want to deploy in Tomcat rather than using executable jars? Depending on the type of diagram, UI could be in the browser because it's a single page application that executes in the browser, the server is used only to deliver the Angular bundle and in fact it could even be delivered by a CDN or by an nginx. Have you looked at the C4 model for describing your architecture? https://c4model.com/ I would rather not expose my domain entities to API, you should consider DTOs. "Services" is rather vague term. Also consider connecting the repository should be connected to the database.

Comment: I want to present the general idea of ​​monolithic architecture so it is not important how we implement this application. I also wanted to find out what the communication of backend with frontend looks like in the application which are generated by jhipster and then show it in the diagram.